# sort complex structure with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I do to sort with SqlAlchemy a complex string, these are the elements inside the column:

```
"0/0/3/1"
"0/2"
"0/0/1"
"0/0/10/1"
"0/5/0/1/3"
"1/0/4/1"
```

the ordering I get by the orm with `db.session.query(Model.Table).order_by(Model.Table.Column)`
It is this: `"0/0/0/1" "0/0/0/10" "0/0/0/2" "0/0/0/20"` that would be the sequence within the string

Comment: The question doesn't really make any sense, what's wrong with `query.order_by(Model.column)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand but ordering them that way gives me a sequence in ascii order, and not in the numeric value
example:
0/0/0/1
0/0/0/10
0/0/0/2
0/0/0/20
that would be the sequence within the string

Comment: Well, from that info, it took me 20 secs to find the term you're after is "natural sort", and you can't do it with sqlalchemy - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863830/2403000

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Since the column has structure, could you consider storing it in separate attributes (splitting in your app layer)?

Comment: the structure is purely dynamic, it does not necessarily have four digits within it, they can be 2 as well as 10

```"5/2" "4/0/0/0/100"```